# How to install some python packages in Docker Container

Tags: python, django, docker

I am using "reportlab".
I have to install "pip install reportlab" every time whenever i entered docker environment, I do not want to install every time it any solution.

Comment: Add `RUN pip install reportlab` to the Dockerfile, or if you already install `requirements.txt` in the Dockerfile, then add `reportlab` to it.

Comment: Docker has an [official tutorial on building and running custom images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) which is a good starting point; it’s even Python-focused, and this should be able to help you out.  Directly installing packages in running containers isn’t a best practice since you’re very likely to lose work.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a `requirements.txt` file and then have something like this in your `Dockerfile`:

```
ADD requirements.txt /code/  # I've assumed code is where you keep your dev files
WORKDIR /code  # where to run docker commands
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt  # install the dependencies
```

You can put not just `reportlab` but all of your other project dependencies in that file (it's a common pattern in Python projects).

Also, depending on how you're running your app you want to make sure you don't remove the container on exiting it.

Answer (score 0):

Login into container, install all necessary components and build an image. That image can be reused to spin new containers.

Docker commit

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/